# How to append extension to files with certain filename format

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I have several files generated by a script but I neglected to have the script append a file extension.

Each filename contains the substring `k120` and no other file in the directory contains that substring.

I would like to append the `.dat` extension to each of these files, but I'm very new to bash (and shell scripting in general) and I'm not sure where to start; how can I rename files based on a substring they contain? I figured I could use `| grep k120` but beyond that I'm not sure.

I could easily do this with a for loop and a regular expression but I'm guessing that's the wrong (long) way to go about it.

Comment: It's in the file name. I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming none of your files have spaces:

```
for i in *k120*; do
    mv -- "$i" "$i.dat"
done
```

Comment: Well ... that's not a thing I knew you could do. How/why does the loop variable get interpreted as "stuff in my directory" as opposed to something else?

Oh, * is a path expansion right?

Comment: As in "$i" and "$i".dat ?

Comment: @Daniel B.  If you did, for example, `ls *k120*`, the shell would expand `*k120*` into a list of files/directories in the current directory before invoking ls to list them.  She shell expands wildcards.

In this case, the shell expands `*k120*` in the same way, so `*k120*` gets expanded into a space-separated list of matching files.  Then the for loop iterates over that list.  Each time through the look $i takes on the name of one of those files.